# Backbone.js and pushState with Laravel backend

Tags: backbone.js, laravel, pushstate

Currently, I'm working on an Backbone.js application and an API is served by Laravel framework. All requests to the server are passed through index.php file which is a part of Laravel framework.

My Backbone.history uses 'pushState',  so when I refresh a page, Laravel takes care of routing and redirects to 404 page.
How to prevent this?

Correct me if i'm doing it wrong way, my Backbone app starts when Laravel renders main view which is a simple html skeleton. Other views and routes are served by Backbone. How to separate this main view from Laravel? I think it causes problem with pushState.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Restful controllers?
And did you added this line into your laravel controller?

#### public $restful = true;